# How to append subdirectories to a list in python

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can only append sub-directories of a given directory to a list in Python.

Something like this is not what I'm searching for as it outputs the files:

```py
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(job['config']['output_dir']):
    for file in files:
        # append the file name to the list
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root, file))
# print all the file names
for name in filelist:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Check if it is directory then add to list `os.path.isdir(file)`

Comment: So why do you add the files and not the directories? What do you think the variable `dirs` contains?

Comment: Just iterate through `dirs` instead of through `files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the dirs variable instead the files variable, like this:

```py
dirs_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('test'):
    for dir in dirs:
        dirs_list.append(os.path.join(root, dir))

print(dirs_list)
```